# Why FindAllAsync give no results if my ParseObject subclasses implements interfaces?

Tags: c#, parse-platform

This query works fine, I get all the expected results:

```
var test = new ParseQuery<User>();
var testList = await test.FindAsync();
```

This query isn't working fine, it gives 0 results:

```
var test = new ParseQuery<ParseMember>();
var testList = await test.FindAsync();
```

I'm absolutely sure that in my Parse DataBase I have a lot of `ParseMember`. It started not working since I changed, in `ParseMember`, from `User` to `IUser` the type of the property `User`. I registered all subclasses. It seems that Parse isn't able to deserialize data into an object with properties that return interfaces.

Why this behaviour? How can I solve that?

---

My objects:

```
[ParseClassName("ParseMember")]
public class ParseMember : ParseObject, IMember
{
    [ParseFieldName("user")]
    public IUser User
    {
        get { return GetProperty<IUser>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }
}

public interface IMember
{
    IUser User { get; set; }
}

public interface IUser
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Alias { get; set; }
    string Username { get; set; }
    string ObjectId { get; set; }
    ParseFile Image { get; set; }
}

public class User : ParseUser, IUser
{
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("alias")]
    public string Alias
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("image")]
    public ParseFile Image
    {
        get { return GetProperty<ParseFile>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code for the `FindAsync` method since that's the one that isn't working.

Comment: @TrevorPilley It isn't a method of mine, but of Parse.com library. http://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/M_Parse_ParseQuery_1_FindAsync_1.htm